# SwiftUI: Expand / Collapse with custom header sometimes results in a blank screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm trying to create a view that has a header at the top (with some text/images) with a table below that has sections that a user can expand and collapse. However, with my current implementation, I'm finding that the screen goes blank on collapse of long sections.

The issue doesn't happen all of the time, but enough to be unacceptable for production. Scrolling up/down refreshes and everything looks OK. When I look at the Xcode View Hierarchy Inspector, it looks like the view height gets messed up after collapse.

I have tried different approaches (Lists, DisclosureGroup) but found that I didn't have full control over styling and layout or there were other issues (e.g, bad animations).

Running on a simulator or device will show the problem - just scroll through and expand/collapse mid-way through the fourth section and it eventually goes blank.

I'm wondering if anyone can see what I might be doing wrong, or does anyone have any ideas on a different approach to achieve the result (needs to run on iOS15 and above)?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isSection1Expanded = true
    @State var isSection2Expanded = true
    @State var isSection3Expanded = true
    @State var isSection4Expanded = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Some text heading (line 1)")
                Text("More header text (line 2)")
                Text("And a little more (line 3)")
                Divider()
                
                // List with sticky headers
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 0, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                        createSection(1...10, section: 1, isExpanded: $isSection1Expanded)
                        createSection(60...65, section: 2, isExpanded: $isSection2Expanded)
                        createSection(70...100, section: 3, isExpanded: $isSection3Expanded)
                        createSection(200...350, section: 4, isExpanded: $isSection4Expanded)
                    }
                }
                .border(.brown)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .navigationTitle("Expand & Collapse")
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func createSection(_ range: ClosedRange<Int>, section: Int, isExpanded: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        Section {
            if isExpanded.wrappedValue {
                ForEach(range, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("S\(section) - Index: \(index)")
                        .frame(height: Double.random(in: 50...120)) // variable height for testing
                }
            }
        } header: {
            sectionHeader(title: "Section \(section)", isExpanded: isExpanded)
        }
        .background(.blue)
        .border(.pink)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func sectionHeader(title: String, isExpanded: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation {
                isExpanded.wrappedValue.toggle()
            }
        } label: {
            HStack(spacing: 4) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
                Text(isExpanded.wrappedValue ? "HIDE" : "SHOW")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding(.trailing)
            }
        }
        .background(.yellow)
        .border(.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to do some more investigations, but I think that this post might help: https://forums.swift.org/t/lazyvstack-not-refreshing-content-size-correctly-for-child-list-container-view-in-swiftui/54299

Comment: So the link above worked in some cases but not all. I gave up with the ScrollView/LazyVStack for iOS 15 & 16 and ended up using a List.